# Python does not follow order of PEMDAS?

Tags: python, multiplication, catalan

I am programming a catalan number generator for homework, and I am doing a recursive program in pytohon.

The program:

```
def catalan(n):
    if n == 0:
        c_f = 1
    else:
        c_f = ((4*n-2)/(n+1))*catalan(n-1)
    return c_f

print catalan(10)
```

returns 5832, which is the wrong answer, but

```
def catalan(n):
    if n == 0:
        c_f = 1
    else:
        c_f = (4*n-2)*catalan(n-1)/(n+1)
    return c_f

print catalan(10)
```

gives me 16796, which is the correct answer.

So does python not follow PEMDAS?

Comment: you are going to have to elaborate ... python of coarse follows pemdas ... maybe you dont quite understand pemdas m==d and a==s so they are simple left to right operations

Answer (score 2):

Just like PEMDAS, python evaluates expressions from left to right. It evaluates `(4*n-2)/(n+1)`, stores it (call the result `X`), and then computes `X/catalan(n-1)`.

The problem is, what is the value of `X`? `(4*n-2)/(n+1)` is not an integer for all values of n, but if you're passing in a value of `n` that is a python `int` *you're performing integer division*. The result is that the fractional part of the computation is discarded, and your computation goes off the rails.

The second iteration works because of a property of the catalan function is that the `(4*n-2)*catalan(n-1)` expression will be a multiple of `n-1`. This way, you leave the (potentially destructive) division to the end of the expression, and the mathematical properties of you computation save you.